# tabula.exe path does not open in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, tabula

I Have specified the path to tabula.exe in pyqt5,when i run the code only the cmd flashes for a second and closes.I have tried the following

```
 def openUrl(self):
      url = QtCore.QUrl('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe')
       if not QtGui.QDesktopServices.openUrl(url):
           QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Open Url', 'Could not open url')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use [`QDesktopServices::openUrl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) it is to signal to the OS that it is necessary to open a file and that it is in charge of looking for the application that can do it. In your case it does not comply with that logic, so the solution is to use [`QProcess::startDetached()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-2):

```py
tabula_path = 'C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Tabula/tabula/tabula.exe'
if QtCore.QProcess.startDetached(tabula_path):
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', 'open a browser and go to http://localhost:8080')
else:
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Problem', 'Problem with tabula')
```

Comment: I tried this but always the else statement executes,I think so because tabula opens in cmd there must be some issue

Comment: @Mihir If the "else" is executed then it is fine, after that open a browser (google chrome, firefox, etc) and place "http://localhost:8080"